# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Method inside dll is not accessible

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to access the function available inside the .dll file. But it give exception like "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: *.jniGetAudioInputLevel()D". DLL file is loaded but when I try to access the methods it give an error message.

According to my knowledge:-

- This exception only occurs if the .dll is not in the class path or the dll is not present in the jar file.
- .dll file is only created if all the code is running with out any error.
- I have seen the methods in the dll using tools like for example: Anywhere PE Viewer, PE Explorer etc. They both are showing the methods available in the .dll file.

How this in accessibility to the function can be configured out by any other idea?

Answer (score 6):

An UnsatisfiedLinkError is also thrown if the native counterpart to a method declared native can't be found.  This can easily happen if the native code was not named with the full Java package name separated using '_'.

For example,

```
package com.mycompany.stuff;

public native void doSomething();
```

Requires that a native library (DLL, so, *SRVPGM, etc depending on your system) be found and loaded with System.loadLibrary(), which contains and exports a function named

```
com_mycompany_stuff_doSomething
```

If you are certain that the native library is being loaded, my guess is that the function is not correctly named, or is not exported.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with **Software Monkey**, but I have one very significant addition related to the function name. The function name in native library should starts from '`_Java_`'. In your case it should be:

```
_Java_com_mycompany_stuff_doSomething
```

I found it by chance and spent two days to figure out why JVM cannot find the function in the DLL if it is there. In my case javah generates header file with function name without underscore sign before 'Java_'. Therefore, I had to update it manually in order to make it work.

I wonder why it was not mentioned about underscore prefix in "The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification", "Java Native Interface 6.0 Specification" provided with Java 6 Documentation (I worked with jdk 1.6.0_30, but the JDK version should not be the issue) and some other resources.

Comment: The prefix seems to be "Java_" on Mac OS X, but "\_Java\_" on Windows XP.

Comment: Evan, you are maybe right. I did not mention that I worked on Windows 7. Unfortunately, I do not have Mac to try it under OS X. But I confused why such small but very important note was not in the mentioned specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we are getting this exception when JVM can't find the .dll file.